# Explain command in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know that when we use the below command in hive it will show the stages involved and the execution flow.

```
>explain select * from tabel1;
```

But in real do we use the explain command only for analysis purpose or any other purpose.

It would be great if any one could explain how exactly **explain** command is used in hive

Comment: Why and how do Oracle DBAs use `explain plan`? Google that one, you will get more answers for Oracle (or Skull Server) than for Hive. But then, the execution plan for an old-fashioned SQL database is way more readable than its Hive equivalent...

Comment: Optimization makes more sense than purely analysis